# Load specific content only when site is visited from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onload

I am building a WordPress site for a client and they want a random quote to display on every page on page load but only when the page is visited from an external source. They don't want it to show when the user is navigating through the site.

How on earth do I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have this solution in my .js now, which works to a certain point.
It's loading on every internal page click. I only want it to load on a page when it's visited from an external source, say google.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var referrer = psl.parse(document.referrer.toString().replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").replace(/\/$/, ""));
        var current = psl.parse(document.location.toString().replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").replace(/\/$/, ""));

        if (referrer.domain !== current.domain) {
            $('.quote-overlay').show().delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    })
```

This is my basic html which is in my header.php file:

```html
<div class="quote-overlay">
  <p>Text content here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is what you are looking for, you can make conditional statements to display your content if certain requirements are fulfilled

Comment: What do I do with that?